# Syntax for Execute On Workstation Unlock

Tags: powershell

I have a script that creates a scheduled task and I need it to run "on workstation unlock", but I can't find the syntax for it.

My intention is to do something like:

```
(New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -whatDoiWriteHere).
```

Comment: All posibble triggers are defined in the offiicial documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtasktrigger?view=win10-ps . `-AtLogOn` seems to fit your need.

Comment: Problem is, the user won't log out it will only lock it self after inactivity. Therefor 
 -AtLogOn won't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`New-ScheduledTaskTrigger` has no support for this particular trigger type (`MSFT_TaskSessionStateChangeTrigger`). Fortunately it's just a wrapper around the existing CIM classes, and you can still use those directly:

```
$stateChangeTrigger = Get-CimClass `
    -Namespace ROOT\Microsoft\Windows\TaskScheduler `
    -ClassName MSFT_TaskSessionStateChangeTrigger

$onUnlockTrigger = New-CimInstance `
    -CimClass $stateChangeTrigger `
    -Property @{
        StateChange = 8  # TASK_SESSION_STATE_CHANGE_TYPE.TASK_SESSION_UNLOCK (taskschd.h)
    } `
    -ClientOnly

$task = New-ScheduledTask -Trigger $onUnlockTrigger -Action ...

Register-ScheduledTask -InputObject $task ...
```

You can easily crib the required values by creating a template task manually in Task Scheduler, then using `Get-ScheduledTask` on that and inspecting its properties.

Interestingly, because the `ScheduledTasks` cmdlets are defined using CDXML metadata only (no explicit code) it should be relatively easy to extend the module to support these types. I haven't looked into that further, though.

Comment: I get an error. Seems like `Register-ScheduledTask` doesn't accept `InputObject` as a parameter

Comment: @Son.Dre: it [definitely does](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/register-scheduledtask); you may be hitting another argument set (for example, if you put `-Action` in there rather than in `New-ScheduledTask`). Otherwise, specify the exact error you're getting; this code snippet was only an example to demonstrate how to get the `-Trigger`.

Comment: Ah, this is how i put it: `Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $jobName -Action $action -InputObject $task -RunLevel Highest -User $user -Settings $settings -Description $Description`

Comment: Yes, to use `-InputObject`, all the task properties have to be given to `New-ScheduledTask` instead. Alternatively, give the `-Trigger` to `Register-ScheduledTask` as well and leave out `New-ScheduledTask`.